# How could I configure Apache to display file names as directories instead?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

For instance, I'd rather `CreateAccount.php` display as `http://www.example.com/CreateAccount/` in the clients' perspective. I know it would be easy to create a lot of directories and fill each of them with an `index.php`, but I'd rather do the most efficient thing. First, to use that method would require a highly unorganised and unnecessarily complex organisation standard. Secondly I'd also rather take full advantage of Apache's features, namely `mod_rewrite`.

I know there's `mod_rewrite`. I'd begun to read the documentation for that module but I'd quickly become *very* confused and a bit frustrated because I have ADHD so it's very hard to sit and read when I know I don't understand what I'm reading.

Could you help me find the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach mod_rewrite is to create a test server/virtual host and slowly build your configuration. Also, try to make your initial rules very simple, so you can exactly understand what every rule does. This configuration can help you start with your process. The last rule is what you need to map your CreateAccount/ path to CreateAccount.php script.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # You can use this only inside of the Directory directive or in the .htaccess file.
    RewriteBase /

    # http://www.example.com/page.html to redirect to http://www.example.com/page.php 
    RewriteRule ^(.*).html /$1.php [L]

    # http://www.example.com/mypath/page.html to redirect to http://www.example.com/mypath/page.php 
    RewriteRule ^mypath/(.*).html /mypath/$1.php [L]

    # http://www.example.com/CreateAccount/ to redirect to http://www.example.com/CreateAccount.php 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```